# Connexion error login in Admin (pb MySQL) with Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

i'm installing Jhipster for the first time, and when launching it, the page web is well displayed but I can't login with admin...
(Failed to sign in! Please check your credentials and try again.)

regarding the npm console, I have this error :

[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/authenticate from localhost:9060 to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Any idea of this problem ?

Generators :
monolythic
no registry
JWT
MySQL (P)
MySQL (Dev)
EhCache
2nd level cache : Hibernate
Maven
Angular
No Sass
No internationalization
Protractor
No Marketspace

---

2019-02-14 15:19:05.673  WARN 23640 --- [ XNIO-2 task-13] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTrait    : Unauthorized: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to
 acquire JDBC Connection
2019-02-14 15:19:05.779  WARN 23640 --- [ XNIO-2 task-13] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceExceptio
n: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Comment: Did you start the java server? see https://www.jhipster.tech/development/.

Comment: Yes, in Eclipse, I right clicked on my main class and executed "Run as Java application"
This automatically launches the browser web.

Comment: Well the IDE may not build everything, so at least for first start you should try with mvnw or gradlew

Comment: Yes, I launched mvnw and obtained this error :

        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointMCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:301)
        ... 147 common frames omitted

[  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

Comment: How do you run mysql? Are you able to connect to itfrom a client like the IDE or DBeaver?

Comment: Thank you Gaël for this good lead... I had a problem with my Workbench. I left it, and created a new database with mysql client... and now all works fine... :-)

Comment: Glad you solved it.